# system cannot find the path specified (could not locate the android sdk at the given path)

Tags: android, api, windows-7, titanium

i installed it and i'm trying to configure t the Android SDK to it error message appear "could not locate the android sdk at the given path" and when i open log file i found this error

```
*****************************************************************************
The system cannot find the path specified. Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\ramzi_shadid\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.0.1\android\avd.py", line 45, in <module> print get_avds(sdk) File "C:\Users\ramzi_shadid\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.0.1\android\avd.py", line 21, in get_avds for line in run.run([sdk.get_android(),'list','target'],debug=False).split("\n"): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
******************************************************************************
```

anyone know's what the solution ?? btw i google it bt no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

does the path to the SDK contain a space? Try moving it to where there is no space.

Comment: program files has a space in it, move it to C:\Android\android-sdk

Comment: yes it does, it's Program Files, NOT ProgramFiles and there is a space in Program Files

Comment: i check it and it still giving me the same error :'(
and i tried to put it on "C:\android-sdk" and still giving me the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I have also had issues on a Windows machine where I put the sdk in a folder under my username.  Eclipse did not reference the folder correctly (c:\user\myname\sdk), but referenced it as (c:\myname\sdk) and so it could not find the sdk.  When you browse for the sdk, go to the c drive and drill down from there.  Dont use the Windows shortcuts.

Comment: yea i know it's on this path "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk" and it doesn't work